# restart javascript variable when change div

Tags: javascript, html

I have two comboboxs and one button in multiple divs. I need to enable the button when the two comboboxs change. This is what I have currently as a Fiddle:

```js
 $size=$('select[name=size]');
     $gender=$('select[name=gender]');
     var op='';
     var ep='';
     
     $size.change(function() {
      op =$(this).val(); 
      myFunction(op,ep);
      
     });
     
     $gender.change(function() {
      ep =$(this).val(); 
      myFunction(op,ep);
     });
     
     function myFunction(p1, p2) {
       if(p1 !='' &&  p2!='') {                 
       $('.nextbutton1').prop('disabled',false);
      } else {
       $('.nextbutton1').prop('disabled', true);
      }   
     }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="someclass">
     <img src="onepic.png">
      <select id="size" name="size">
          <option value=""></option>
          <option value="1">one</option>
          <option value="2">two</option>
      </select>
      <select id="gender" name="gender">
          <option value=""></option>
          <option value="1">one</option>
          <option value="2">two</option>
       </select>
       <button class="nextbutton1">button</button>
    </div>
    
    <div class="someclass">
     <img src="twopic.png">
      <select id="size" name="size">
          <option value=""></option>
          <option value="1">one</option>
          <option value="2">two</option>
      </select>
      <select id="gender" name="gender">
          <option value=""></option>
          <option value="1">one</option>
          <option value="2">two</option>
       </select>
       <button class="nextbutton1">button</button>
    </div>
```

but when I change the div, the button from the second div is already enabled. How can I reset the variables from the script?

Comment: you mean to say, first button should be enabled only when you select first two select boxes and second button should be enabled only when you select second two select boxes ?

Comment: You shouldn't have Elements with the same IDs, IDs are required by HTML Spec to be unique

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Container
   - Combobox1
   - Combobox2
   - NextButton
Container
   - Combobox1
   - Combobox2
   - NextButton
```

Loop through Containers and set event listeners for Comboboxes inside each Container separately

```
$('.someclass').each(function () {
    setOnComboboxChange($(this));
});

function setOnComboboxChange($container) {
    // Use var keyword to create functional scope variables
    var $size = $container.find('select[name=size]');
    var $gender = $container.find('select[name=gender]');
    var $nextBtn = $container.find('.nextbutton1');
    var op = '';
    var ep = '';

    $size.change(function () {
        op = $(this).val();  
        myFunction(op, ep);
    });

    $gender.change(function () {
        ep = $(this).val();  
        myFunction(op, ep);
    });

    function myFunction(p1, p2) {
        if (p1 != '' && p2 != '') {                 
            $nextBtn.prop('disabled', false);
        } else {
            $nextBtn.prop('disabled', true);
        }   
    }
}
```

[Demo on Codepen](https://codepen.io/vanquyet/pen/jOEwgyO)

Answer (score 0):

just another solution,

you can assign `class` to each controls and then attach change event to the dropdowns,
and then find the button within parent container using jquery

HTML:

```
<div class="someclass">
 <img src="onepic.png">
  <select class="size myFunction">
      <option value=""></option>
      <option value="1">one</option>
      <option value="2">two</option>
  </select>
  <select class="gender myFunction">
      <option value=""></option>
      <option value="1">one</option>
      <option value="2">two</option>
   </select>
   <button class="nextbutton1" disabled>button</button>
</div>

<div class="someclass">
 <img src="twopic.png">
  <select class="size myFunction">
      <option value=""></option>
      <option value="1">one</option>
      <option value="2">two</option>
  </select>
  <select class="gender myFunction">
      <option value=""></option>
      <option value="1">one</option>
      <option value="2">two</option>
   </select>
   <button class="nextbutton1" disabled>button</button>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".myFunction").change(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    var $container = $($this.parent(".someclass"));
    var $next = $($container.find(".nextbutton1"));
    var $size = $($container.find(".size"));
    var $gender = $($container.find(".gender"));

    var p1 = $size.val();
    var p2 = $gender.val();

    if(p1 !='' &&  p2!='') {                 
      $next.prop('disabled',false);
    } else {
      $next.prop('disabled', true);
    }  
  });
});
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xwgz3doj/